# How to update state in JavaScript with React and Redux?

Tags: javascript

1. userData is stored in Redux in the format [{name: 'haney', age: 30, login: false}, {name: 'billi', age: 30, login: false}].
2. I want to change the login value to true in userData every time a user logs in.
   For example, it would be like [{name: 'haney', age:30, **login:true**}, {name: 'billi', age:30, login:false}]
3. I have tried every method I know, but when I check the console.log, the login value is still false. Please help me.

```
//data store (redux)
let users = createSlice({
  name: "users",
  initialState: [],
  reducers: {
    addUsers(state, action) {
      const newUsers = { ...action.payload };
      return [...state, { ...newUsers }];
    },

    setUsers(state, action) {
      const [id, newInfo] = action.payload;
      console.log(newInfo);
      return state.map((user) => {
        if (user.id === id) {
          return { ...user, ...newInfo };
        }
      });
    },

   setLoginStatus(state, action) {
      const { userId, loginStatus } = action.payload;
      return state.map(user => {
        if (user.id === userId) {
          return { ...user, login: loginStatus };
        }
        return user;
      });
    }
 
});

export const { addUsers, setUsers, setLoginStatus } = users.actions;

export default configureStore({
  reducer: {
    users: users.reducer,
  },
});

//main code
const Login = () => {
  let Dispatch = useDispatch();
  let users = useSelector((state) => {
    return state.users;
  });
  const loginCheck = () => {
    const user = users.find((user) => user.id === formdata.id);

    if (user) {
      if (user.password === formdata.password) {
        Dispatch(setLoginStatus({ userId: user.id, loginStatus: true }));
        alert(`${user.name}, hello!`);
        console.log(users);
        movePage("/nav/home");
      } else {
        alert("password wrong");
      }
    } else {
      alert("id wrong");
    }
  };
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aOSNS.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VcpQz.png)

At first, I tried to manipulate everything with the setUser reducer, but failed. Then I tried again with a simpler setLoginStatus, but failed again. No matter what I do, the login value won't change

Comment: You are returning values from the reducers. You should update the state itself instead. Read the Documentation (https://react-redux.js.org/tutorials/quick-start)

Answer (score 0):

Slight change in setLoginStatus reducer

```
setLoginStatus(state,action){
    const {userId, loginStatus}=action.payload
    const userToUpdate = state.find(user=>user.id === userId)
    if(userToUpdate){
       userToUpdate.login = loginStatus
    }
}
```

Comment: "I did as you said. Even after the 1st login, the 'login' value still shows as false. However, after logging out and logging in again for the 2nd time, it finally shows as 'true'. I can't figure out the reason.

Comment: If you are connected to database, you can add one more field to user for status. After login you can directly update the status to true.